# Get current connections to MongoDB in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How do I get the current amount of connections to my MongoDB collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this query:

```
db.serverStatus().connections
```

Should return a response containing the current, available, and total created connections.

More info in the official documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#connections